# replace dynamically onclick handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I insert dynamically some images used as buttons and add an onClick event.

```
$("img.image_edit_customer").live("click", function() {
    // when clicking the edit image of a row
    $(this).manipulateCustomer("editRowCustomer", {
        scope : "#customer_tbody"
    });
});
```

Later I want to remove the onClick event from the image used as button.

```
$('img[class^="image_edit"]').live('click', function() {
    // do nothing from now on
    alert('edit');
});
```

Now, it always executes the old **and** the new handler.

**UPDATE**

If I'm using `die('click');`, I can still execute the onCLick event once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery 1.7+

To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself:

```
$(document).one("click", "img.image_edit_customer", function() {
    $(this).manipulateCustomer("editRowCustomer", {
        scope : "#customer_tbody"
    });
});
```

To attach an event that can be remove at a later time:

```
$(document).on("click", "img.image_edit_customer", editRow);
```

To remove the event:

```
$(document).off("click", "img.image_edit_customer", editRow);
```

Function to attach and remove

```
function editRow(e) {
   $(e.target).manipulateCustomer("editRowCustomer", {
       scope : "#customer_tbody"
   });
}
```

Comment: Yes it should, any element that can have a handler attached should work with this method. It listens on the document level for any 'click' event that bubbles up, so as long as the selector for the targeted element is correct it will work, but you should try to use a closer parent than 'document', that is of course not dynamicly insterted, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are attaching the events with live method, you need to use die method

http://api.jquery.com/die/

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `.live()` to bind the event you need to use the [`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) method to remove the event-handler:

```
$('img[class^="image_edit"]').die('click');
```

**Notice**

As of jQuery 1.7, it is recommended to use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods instead, to attach and de-attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than unbinding or killing (aka die) the events for all matched elements, I'd mark the individual elements with a 'marker' class like so:

```
$("img.image_edit_customer").live("click", function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
       $(this).addClass('clicked');
       $(this).manipulateCustomer("editRowCustomer", {
           scope : "#customer_tbody"
       });
    }
});
```